# Systemd backed tmpfs | How to specify /tmp size manually

Tags: systemd, disk, tmpfs, quota

I mount `/tmp` on `tmpfs` using:

```
sudo systemctl enable tmp.mount
sudo systemctl start tmp.mount
```

But this way `/tmp` takes up all the free RAM:

```
$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /tmp
$
```

**How do I tell systemd tmp.mount to use only 1G?** I know I can alternatively not use systemd and manually add an entry to `/etc/fstab` and specify the size there. But I don't want to do that. I want to use systemd backed tmpfs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [systemd way](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) of overriding `tmp.mount`, or extending it, is to add a local override in `/etc/systemd/system`. You can either copy the existing `tmp.mount` (from `/lib/systemd/system` or `/usr/share/systemd` probably) and edit the copy, or better yet, add configuration snippets to only change the mount options, by running

```
sudo systemctl edit tmp.mount
```

and entering

```
[Mount]
Options=mode=1777,strictatime,nosuid,nodev,size=1G
```

in the editor which opens. This will

- create a directory called `/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount.d`
- inside that directory, add a file called `override.conf` containing the text above.

Note that [`systemd.mount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) still says that

> In general, configuring mount points through `/etc/fstab` is the preferred approach.

so you may just want to do that, *i.e.* edit `/etc/fstab` to add the `size=...` option on the `/tmp` line (adding it if necessary):

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs mode=1777,strictatime,nosuid,nodev,size=1G 0 0
```

In fact, this is the recommended approach to change mount options for any of [systemd’s “API file systems”](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/):

> Even though normally none of these API file systems are listed in `/etc/fstab` they may be added there. If so, any options specified therein will be applied to that specific API file system. Hence: to alter the mount options or other parameters of these file systems, simply add them to `/etc/fstab` with the appropriate settings and you are done. Using this technique it is possible to change the source, type of a file system in addition to simply changing mount options. That is useful to turn `/tmp` to a true file system backed by a physical disk.

API file systems include the following: `/sys`, `/proc`, `/dev`, `/run`, `/tmp`, `/sys/fs/cgroup`, `/sys/kernel/security`, `/sys/kernel/debug`, `/sys/kernel/config`, `/sys/fs/selinux`, `/dev/shm`, `/dev/pts`, `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc`, `/dev/mqueue`, `/dev/hugepages`, `/sys/fs/fuse/connections`, `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`. systemd ensures they are mounted even if they are not specified in `/etc/fstab` or a mount unit.

Be careful when sizing `tmpfs` file systems: they will end up competing with whatever else in your system needs memory (including swap), and can result in memory exhaustion when you don’t expect it; at worst [this can result in deadlocks](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html).

Comment: Based on https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html you can use symbolic values for `size` using suffixes. Example: `size=1G`.  Side story: I just discovered that if you don't specify anything the kernel takes... 50% of the RAM for this tmpfs, which is probably nowadays crazy. This was killing my 32GB laptop...

Comment: Yes, the default of 50% can be surprising; but it’s strange that that would kill your laptop, because a `tmpfs` only allocates memory as needed to store the data (*up to* the configured size).

Comment: As the page says: "If you oversize your tmpfs instances the machine will deadlock since the OOM handler will not be able to free that memory." Heavy applications over consuming memory were exactly triggering this and I now resized my /tmp to be far smaller and I hope not to have deadlocks anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is very old and not necessarily accurate; I think there’s a bit more to it than “set `size` too large → deadlock”. I have several `tmpfs` mounts using the default settings, and as long as they don’t fill up too much my system works fine (including swapping out the `tmpfs` contents as necessary). It’s even possible to mount a `tmpfs` with a `size` far larger than installed memory or even RAM+swap, without adverse effects (as long as it’s not too full of course). Of course limiting `tmpfs` size is a good idea, I’m not saying the contrary.

Comment: I guess all is in the "and as long as they don’t fill up too much" and "ncluding swapping out the tmpfs contents as necessary" (I didn't have real swap enabled), hence many variations in behavior possible. I just reduced my `/tmp` (from 16 to 1G) and I hope it resolves my mad deadlocks/OOMs, I will see... I can't vouch that it is the real root cause (even if it is clearly memory related) but at least I thought pointing out that bit in documentation can help others... of course if it is still current, that I don't know.

Comment: Good point about warning readers, I’ve added a paragraph about sizing.

Comment: For Debian/Ubuntu you may need to make `tmp.mount` available first with `sudo ln -s /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount /etc/systemd/system/`. Then when overriding the size via `sudo systemctl edit tmp.mount`, use the existing `Options` line as a base in case it contains additional mount options.