# Why is there a `proc` mount in fstab

Tags: fstab

I have a `proc` mount entry in my fstab on (Debian derived) Raspberry Pi OS. Is this one needed? On my pc (running Arch linux) I don't have this but (of course) `proc` gets mounted.

fstab line:

```
proc        /proc       proc    defaults    0 0
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux website 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Historically, `/proc` wasn’t automatically mounted, which is why some systems still list it in `/etc/fstab`.

Nowadays systemd takes care of mounting a number of [“API file systems”](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/) including `/proc`, so any system running systemd will have `/proc` mounted whether it’s listed in `/etc/fstab` or not.

API file systems may still appear in `/etc/fstab` since that’s the documented way of overriding mount settings; see [Systemd backed tmpfs | How to specify /tmp size manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352042/86440) for details.

Comment: +1 and accept, nice explanation. so i can remove that entry? my system is fully updated but it was flashed 3+ years ago (apr 18) (does that even matter?)

Comment: If the system is running systemd (`/run/systemd` exists), yes, you can remove that entry.

Comment: @Antoni: And your system **is** running `systemd`, so yes - you can remove the entry in`/etc/fstab`. The only exception would be if you've removed `systemd` - which would be highly unusual.