# tmp on tmpfs: fstab vs tmp.mount with systemd

Tags: systemd, mount, fstab, tmpfs, tmp

To have `/tmp` on tmpfs, I know I can use an entry in `/etc/fstab`, but I do not understand the role of `/etc/default/tmpfs` [mentioned](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/initscripts/tmpfs.5.en.html) sometimes, and in what case I need to create or modify it.

Recently, I often see suggested to use systemd `tmp.mount` confuguration. For example, [on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization/#Reduction_of_SSD_write_frequency_via_RAMDISK):

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount /etc/systemd/system/
$ sudo systemctl enable tmp.mount
```

Which of the two methods is more appropriate for everyday use? In what situations one is better than the other? When do I need to deal with `/etc/default/tmpfs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On some systems, `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` by default, and this is the configuration [provided by systemd’s “API File Systems”](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/). Fedora-based systems follow this pattern to various extents; Fedora itself ships `/usr/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount` and enables it, but RHEL 8 ships it without enabling it. On such systems, masking and unmasking the unit is the appropriate way of disabling or enabling a `tmpfs` `/tmp`, [as documented in the API File Systems documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/#whyareyoutellingmeallthisijustwanttogetridofthetmpfsbackedtmp).

Other systems such as Debian [don’t ship `tmp.mount` in a directly-usable location](https://bugs.debian.org/783509); this is why you need to copy it to `/etc/systemd/system` if you want to use it. This has the unfortunate side-effect of creating a full override of `tmp.mount` in `/etc`, which means that if the `systemd` package ships a different version of `tmp.mount` in `/lib/systemd/system` in the future, it will be ignored. On such systems I would recommend using `/etc/fstab` instead.

In both setups, `/etc/fstab` is still the recommended way of [customising `/tmp` mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352042/86440), *e.g.* to change their size; [`man systemd.mount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab) says

> In general, configuring mount points through `/etc/fstab` is the preferred approach to manage mounts for humans.

and [the API File Systems documentation concurs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/#whyareyoutellingmeallthisijustwanttogetridofthetmpfsbackedtmp).

Using mount units is [recommended for tooling](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab), *i.e.* for automated configuration:

> For tooling, writing mount units should be preferred over editing `/etc/fstab`.

(This means that tools which want to automatically set up a mount shouldn’t try to edit `/etc/fstab`, which is error-prone, but should instead install a mount unit, which can be done atomically and can also be overridden by a system administrator using systemd features.)

`/etc/default/tmpfs` is used by Debian’s `sysvinit`, so it’s irrelevant with systemd.

Answer (score 0):

I always disable /tmp being a /tmpfs because it takes away from valuable RAM especially on systems like Raspberry Pi.
Thus, I use **systemctl mask tmp.mount** to disable it on systemd.
Also, I don't want my /tmp to be cleared with every boot nor do I want to think about storing semi-temporary files in /var/tmp.
Temporary to me means "not system critical" but it doesn't mean "unnecessary between boots".
Thus, I use /tmp for everything with a short lifetime and do housekeeping on it.
So if you work mostly as a single user on your system, I recommend to keep /tmp on the root partition and not separate it at all.
This also allows to temporarily save large files in /tmp like compressed archives, downloads etc. without running out of memory or reserving a large portion of disk space just for /tmp.