# changes to /dev/shm mount options revert after reboot, ubuntu 18.04

Tags: filesystems, mount

I use Ubuntu 18.04 on an embedded system.
By default it has tmpfs mounted on `/dev/shm` with 3.8G (~half RAM size) and some mount options.

I'm trying to change the `/dev/shm` size and mount options via the `/etc/fstab`.
If I remount it, it works until next reboot, getting default values afterwards.

1. I read that systemd can be used to configure this filesystem but they still recommend using the fstab file:
   [Systemd backed tmpfs | How to specify /tmp size manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352042/systemd-backed-tmpfs-how-to-specify-tmp-size-manually)
2. I read that some people changed the `/etc/fstab` entry from `/dev/shm` to `/run/shm`,
   but after doing so I had both filesystems mounted, not linked to each other:
   https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/232487
3. I read that on redhat distributions , the `/dev/shm` is being mounted via boot from rc scripts but `grep -r '/dev/shm' /etc/rc*/*` returned nothing useful.

So how can I assure the `/dev/shm` mount options in `/etc/fstab` will take effect after reboot?

Comment: Does your embedded system have `systemd-remount-fs.service`?

Comment: I tried "systemctl mask dev-shm.mount" and "systemctl mask run-shm.mount" but still the changes in /etc/fstab regarding /dev/shm didn't apply (tried to reboot the system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I performed the following actions:

1. Created some new partitions with ext4 filesystems.
2. Mounted these new filesystems (on /var , /var/log , /home , and more..) and added suitable entries in /etc/fstab.
3. Added new entries for tmpfs on /tmp and /dev/shm in /etc/fstab

When I perform step 3 before the others I get the desired results - the /dev/shm mount options remained changed even after reboot.

I don't know the exact reason but maybe the precedence of the /dev/shm entry upon the others in /etc/fstab has something to do with that.