# How do I set the size of /run (tmpfs)

Tags: systemd, rhel, tmpfs, alma-linux

I’m running AlmaLinux 9.2 (systemd v.252) on a small embedded(-ish) system, where I like to keep a lot of stuff in `/run`. When I was using CentOS7.x this was on the order of 1.5G, and I never really thought about it. However, since we have moved to Alma9, the default size of `/run` is only ~720M on the same hardware.

I can set the size by adding a line in `/etc/fstab` - but that seems a bit old-fashioned these days. For the `/run/user/<uid>` I can set a parameter `RuntimeDirectorySize` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, but I haven’t found anything similar for the entire `/run`.

Surely there must be a systemd-specific way of specifying this?

(The [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352042/systemd-backed-tmpfs-how-to-specify-tmp-size-manually) talks primarily about `/tmp` - but it turns out to be equally applicable for e.g. `/run`.)

Comment: Thanks! That's _very_ close to what I'm looking for. Not 100%, but I think it's close enough. I'll formulate an answer myself, based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by Stephen Kitt, it looks like the recommended mechanism is indeed to edit the `/etc/fstab`. Quoting from [the systemd docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/):

> Even though normally none of these API file systems are listed in /etc/fstab they may be added there. If so, any options specified therein will be applied to that specific API file system. Hence: to alter the mount options or other parameters of these file systems, simply add them to /etc/fstab with the appropriate settings and you are done.

The relevant keyword is `API file system` - which includes all(?) the 'irregular' filesystems such as `/sys`, `/proc`, `/dev`, but also `/tmp`, `/run` and others.